# How to export the virtual environment settings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am new to python and pycharm tool. I have created a project and checked in Git hub. Now one of my friend pulled the changes and tried to run and he encountered with an error message stating "No interpreters found". When i revalidated the project structure i found that i have 'venv' folder in my project but the person who pulled the changes dosent have it.

Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance!

PS: I am using Windows OS

Comment: `venv` should not be put in git. this is you local library storage for this project, your friend should do the same, and do https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html then he'll install the lib on his laptop, but NEVER share lib installation, this is huge NEVER do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said you're new to Python, I'll try to explain how things work in Python projects.

Steps to do setup on your another machine.

1. Export all the installed and used packages for your project using `pip freeze` and write them to a text file which contains library names and versions. Add this file to your project. Convention is to name it as `requirements.txt`. Refer this https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/
2. Create a virtual environment in another machine with same python version.
3. Activate the environment and install the libraries again using the file you've exported initially.

**Note:** It's **not** suggested to have venv folder which contains all your packages inside your project directory itself. You may have to add the folder to `.gitignore` just for this purpose.

You might want to take a look at `.idea` folder in project directory. But I don't think that would be much useful.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't check in your venv folder.

Save the output of `pip freeze` in a file called `requirements.txt` and check that into your repo.

Once your friend gets the full code, they can install the dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt`